# Positioning a div near bottom side of another div

Tags: html, css, layout

I have outer div and inner div. I need to place inner div at the bottom of the outer one.

Outer div is elastic (width: 70% for example). I also need to center inner block.

Simple model of described make-up is shown on the picture below:

[image]

Comment: is the height elastic as well? If not, you could set the margin-top for the inner box to (outerBoxHeight - innerBoxHeight).

Comment: @peirix: yes, outer block's height can change and we don't know it

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Tested and working on Firefox 3, Chrome 1, and IE 6, 7 and 8:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><body>
<div style='background-color: yellow; width: 70%;
            height: 100px; position: relative;'>
    Outer
    <div style='background-color: green;
                position: absolute; left: 0; width: 100%; bottom: 0;'>
        <div style='background-color: magenta; width: 100px;
                    height: 30px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center'>
            Inner
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Live version here: http://jsfiddle.net/RichieHindle/CresX/

Comment: Thank you, your solution is almost correct. I only had to add "//margin-left: -40px" to green block's style for IE. Without this hack with margin-left attribute your green block was disposed left in IE7. Can anyone explain where this 40px comes from?

Comment: IE7 was horizontally positioning the green div after the word "Outer".  I've updated the code to specify "left: 0".

Answer (score 13):

You need a wrapping div for the bottom one, in order to center it.

```
<style>
   /* making it look like your nice illustration */
   #outer { width: 300px; height: 200px; background: #f2f2cc; border: 1px solid #c0c0c0; }
   #inner { width: 50px; height: 40px; background: #ff0080; border: 1px solid #800000; }

   /* positioning the boxes correctly */
   #outer { position: relative; }
   #wrapper { position: absolute; bottom: 3px; width: 100%; }
   #inner { margin: 0 auto; }
</style>


<div id="outer">
   <div id="wrapper"><div id="inner"></div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

CSS3 `Flexbox` allows the bottom positioning very easily. Check the [**Flexbox support table**](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* Center content inside */
}
.inner {
  align-self: flex-end; /* At the bottom of the parent */
}
```

**Output:**

```css
.outer {
  background: #F2F2CD;
  display: flex;
  width: 70%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid #C2C2C3;
  justify-content: center;
}
.inner {
  background: #FF0081;
  width: 75px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #810000;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Works well on all browsers including ie6.

```
<style>
    #outer{
        width: 70%;
        background-color: #F2F2CC;
        border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
        height: 500px;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #inner{
        background-color: #FF0080;
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 30px;
        height: 20px;

        /* Position at the bottom */
        position: relative;
        top: 95%;

        /* Center */
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: left;
    }
</style>

<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: top 95% isn't the same as saying bottom 10px. You want the inner box to anchor at the bottom as the screen is resized.