# Positioning div at bottom inline

Tags: html, css

I need to position some images, inline on the bottom of a container.
I tried to do as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857916/positioning-a-div-near-bottom-side-of-another-div) question asks, but I can't understand why with me doesn't work and escapes from the container.
Could you help me? This is my code:

```
<div id="banner">
<div id="uscite">
    <div id="jp"><img src="../img/uscite/scan.png" height="90" width="60" alt="" /><br />text</div>
    <div id="it"><img src="../img/uscite/scan.png" height="90" width="60" alt="" /><br />text</div>
</div>
<div id="nav_main">
    <div style="margin: 0 auto;"><img src="../inc/home.png" /></div>
    <div style="margin: 0 auto;"><img src="../inc/staff.png" /></div>
    <div style="margin: 0 auto;"><img src="../inc/forum.png" /></div>
    <div style="margin: 0 auto;"><img src="../inc/disclaimer.png" /></div>
    <div style="margin: 0 auto;"><img src="../inc/secret.png" /></div>    
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
div#banner{
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #444444;
    background: url('header2.png') no-repeat center center;
    height:400px;
}

div#nav_main{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 1180px; 
    bottom: 0;
}
div#uscite{
    padding:30px 20px;
    float:right;
    border:0px;
    height:35%;
    width:20%;
}

div#jp{
    text-align: center;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    border:0px;
}
div#it{
    text-align: center;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    float:right;
    border:0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nu7eoj0q/1/

Edit: I'd also like add another div (called "social") under "uscite"'s one. but it doesn't appear. What am I wrong?
http://jsfiddle.net/faeba3v1/

Comment: Can you simplify the problem by letting only 2 available images that really work in jsfiddle? (online sources)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to do this

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/nu7eoj0q/4/)

new properties added

```
#nav_main div{
    display:inline-block;
}

div#banner{
   position:relative;
}
```

Comment: I was waiting. It said I should wait 2 minutes xD

Comment: Hi sorry, I edited this post with another question about another problem like this one. Could you help me?

Comment: It doesn't appear anything, like my try (and yes, images are on the right path)